# API Error Code: 191 with HybridAuth

Tags: facebook, hybridauth

I'm using the Laravel framework and am in the process of moving to Laravel 4 and HybridAuth. The site I'm building has login via Facebook and Linkedin, and Linkedin is working fine while Facebook gives me the API Error Code: 191.

I followed [this](http://www.mrcasual.com/on/coding/laravel4-package-management-with-composer/) guide to set it up with Laravel4, so my base url is at: http://mywebsite.com/social/auth
According to [this](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/IDProvider_info_Facebook.html) page, the callback url for facebook should be http://mywebsite.com/path_to_hybridauth/?hauth.done=Facebook, so I've tried setting my Site URL@Facebook to http://mywebsite.com/auth/social/?hauth.done=Facebook with no success.

When looking at the URL after the redirect to facebook (when I see the error) there is a redirect_uri GET-parameter which looks like: http://mywebsite.com/auth/social?hauth.done=Facebook&state=[random-numbers]&scope=email&display=page, is this the address I need to specify in the Site URL to Facebook? This would however not be possible, since it has random numbers in it.

I've also set App Domains, which I didn't need before I got HybridAuth.

My question to the HybridAuth-users would be, how do I set the Site URL so I don't get the 191 error?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter a domain/subdomain in the facebook app settings "App Domains" field.

Comment: I have, which I also wrote in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to enter the whole URL for the "Site URL" on Facebook. I have it set to just the domain name and it works fine for me. The "App domain" is the same.